# receving ng-select value as an object

Tags: angularjs, node.js

HTML

```
<select ng-model="data.trackId" 
    ng-value="track.id" 
    ng-options="track.name for track in tracks">
</select>
```

on the server end I'm receiving the track as an object.

```
{ name: 'gadf',
  room: 'asdf',
  start: '0:55',
  end: '0:55',
  dayId: 4,
  trackId: { id: 3, name: 'track 3', color: '#FFFFCC' },
  color: 'gasdf',
  description: 'asdf' }
```

Expectation:

I'd like to receive trackId as 3

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, you say *on the server end I'm receiving the track as an object.*, but I don't see any http call to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-value` is not necessary, try:

```
<select ng-model="data.trackId" 
    ng-options="track.trackId.id as track.name for track in tracks">
</select>
```

Update: **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TEQrWVss4Zey75Mwwskj?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks, how can I preselect the value in the select box based on scope value, `$scope.data.trackId = 3`

Comment: @user2727195 ng-value is not necessary if you're using a model. Check **Update**

Comment: thanks, I'm getting the value back, but how do I manually set a value through $scope.data.trackId = 5 let's say

Comment: Default value (first item): `$scope.data.trackId = $scope.tracks[0].trackId.id`

Comment: for some reason, Iit's not working, my slightly modified case is working, hopefully you can shed light on this, posting another question now, I'll accept this.

Comment: mind looking at this please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659013/ng-select-with-lazy-population

Comment: this works though but it's not pre-selecting the combo box on form edit