# ng-select with lazy population

Tags: angularjs

It's an edit form with parent record first populated then dependent select list is populated, and then it's expected the value from parent record pre-select the combo box.

html

```
<select ng-model="data.trackId" >
    <option ng-repeat="track in tracks" value="{{track.id}}">{{track.name}}</option>
```

initial result once parent record is pulled.

```
if(data) {
            this.$scope.data.id = data.id;
            this.$scope.data.name = data.name;
            this.$scope.data.room = data.room;
            this.$scope.data.start = data.start;
            this.$scope.data.end = data.end;
            this.$scope.data.dayId = data.day_id;
            this.$scope.data.trackId = data.track_id;
            this.$scope.data.color = data.color;
            this.$scope.data.description = data.description;
            this.$scope.$apply();
            this.$element[0].removeAttribute("style");
        }
```

//later track results were pulled

```
trackResult: function(data, status, headers, config) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        this.$scope.tracks.push(data[i]);
    }
    this.$scope.$apply();
},
```

Problem:

List gets populated from the second call `trackResult` but default value from the $scope.trackId never sets the combo box to a value.

Edit: Controller Body

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
    var self = this;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$scope.data = {};
    this.$scope.days = [];
    this.$scope.tracks = [];
    this.$scope.submit = function() {self.submit()};
    this.$scope.cancel = function() {self.cancel()};
},
```

Comment: could show the controller body for avoid using $apply?

Comment: why you used this `this.$scope`? it should use `$scope` directly

Comment: added controller body, I'm saving the instance of the $scope, because updates happen outside the scope, therefore using $apply

Comment: Exactly, use `$scope` instead of `this`, change it in all its properties

Comment: in `trackResult` function, $scope is not available, therefore the stored version of this.$scope

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : Updated with setting the data from outside the scope (OP request)

---

## Use `ng-options` & `ng-model`

this is how i think it should be done in angularjs.
use the built in databinding capabilities to simplify your code and make it less complicated

for binding a list into a `<select>` and controlling the selected item, this snippet below should do the trick.

### http://jsfiddle.net/72em40j4/

**js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = [];
    $scope.selectedOption = null;
});
```

**html**

```
<script>
    function clickFromOutside() {
        var controllerElement = document.getElementById('container');
        var controllerScope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope();


        var firstTrack = {
            id: 1,
            first: 'First',
            last: 'Track'
        };

        var secondTrack = {
            id: 2,
            first: 'Second',
            last: 'Track'
        };

        controllerScope.options.push(firstTrack);
        controllerScope.options.push(secondTrack);

        controllerScope.selectedOption = secondTrack;

        controllerScope.$apply();


    }
</script>

<button onclick="clickFromOutside();">outside</button>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset id="container" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in options" ng-model="selectedOption"></select> <pre>{{ selectedOption }}</pre>

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: you're referencing the original options array, how about if let's say id, 2, or 3 coming from outside the $scope, and then `$apply()`

Comment: why using `$apply()` in the first place?

Comment: because data update is coming from outside the $scope, data is manually set in $scope,

Comment: check it out now. you can still use angular binding capabilities even if you hack the data from outside the scope. i must say i don't know why this can't be done in pure angular, but since you need it this way, here's how :)

Comment: interesting, you've done it in a bit different way, I'll get back to you on this, thanks for the attempt